# Pulling a branch into xcode gets the files but not the changes to add them to project itself

Tags: xcode, git

I'm going up to a cottage for a couple of days and would like to work on one of my pet projects. I'll be using my wife's MBA so I'm trying to pull the [latest branch from GitHub](https://github.com/maurymarkowitz/RetroBASIC/branches).

On GitHub there are two branches, `master` and the current branch, `glib-remove`. The main difference in the latter is the addition of two new files, `data.h` and `data.c` and changes to the Xcode project file to add them.

When I pulled the branch to the MBA I was mystified, as the files did not appear in the project. It turns it they *were* pulled, but the project file doesn't have them included. I'm a bit of a loss why this might be. The project is listed as clean on the original machine, it's definitely in the repo, but doing a pull on that file on the MBA does nothing.

Can someone suggest why this might be happening? It's easy enough to simply add the files to the project manually, but I'd like to know what's going on so I can avoid it in the future.

Comment: Git just stores files in commits as directed by whatever's directing it, so presumably XCode didn't direct it to store an updated project file. That would make this an xcode question...

Comment: When I added the files to the Xcode project, the project file was marked with an M, and when I did my commit, the M went away. But when I pulled to the other machine, it did not seem to get the updated project.

Comment: You can bypass Xcode entirely (just don't run it at all) and look at what Git did (by running Git commands from the shell). I don't normally use Xcode but my sneaky suspicion at this point is that the files did get updated and merged properly but then your Xcode changed things back (incorrectly, based on some faulty assumption your Xcode was making, for reasons known only to it).